# Can't access public const?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, constants, .net-6.0

I have a class `Port` representing port's number with min and max value limits.

```
public class Port
{
    public const int MinPortNumber = 1025;
    public const int MaxPortNumber = ushort.MaxValue;

    private readonly int _portNumber;

    private Port(int portNumber)
    {
        _portNumber = portNumber;
    }

    public static implicit operator int(Port port) => port._portNumber;
    public override string ToString() => $"{_portNumber}";

    public static Port FromNumber(int portNumber)
    {
        Validate(portNumber);
        return new Port(portNumber);
    }
    
    private static void Validate(int port)
    {
        if (port is < MinPortNumber or > MaxPortNumber)
            throw PortRangeException.NotInRange(port, MinPortNumber, MaxPortNumber);
    }
}
```

I was trying to access it's value from another project, but on build I receive compilation error [CS1061]:

```
public class ServiceViewModel
{
    public ServiceViewModel()
    {
        _port = Port.MinPortNumber;
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int _port;
}
```

I accessed this const in same project like

```
if ((int)(service.Port) is < Port.MinPortNumber or > Port.MaxPortNumber) {}
```

and it has worked.

So, why doesn't compiler allow me to access this const in that case?

Comment: Did you add a refrence to the other project? Are you missing a `using` directive?

Comment: Yes, I did and there is a `using` directive

Comment: I found out, that I can't access any members of this `Port` class

Comment: Does `ServiceViewModel` happen to have a property `Port`? Then the `Port` identifier would refer to this, not the class.

Comment: Ah, sure! I used code-generator and forgot, that property with name `Port` was generated. Thank you!

Comment: This is why it is so useful to post a [mre] here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake.

Private field `[ObservableProperty] private int _port;` generates `Port` property, so it hides `Port` class behind it.

Solution was to rename this field and regenerate property.

```
[ObservableProperty] private int _portNumber = Port.MinPortNumber;
```